# Application failed to resume in time : Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am populating my core data with thousands of records in multiple entities one by one. This process is taking time to complete. This process is working fine when app is in active state. Once app goes in background and comes in foreground, the app is crashing with following error:

"failed to resume in time ios crash"

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The creating of the Core Data stack should never be done in the -`applicationDidFinishLaunching` If a migration is needed just inform the user about it but you need to return from the -`applicationDidFinishLaunching`... as fast as possible, you should only be creating UI elements in this method. You should not be accessing Core Data at this point.

Comment: I am doing nothing in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method. I am just performing process in viewDidLoad moethod of main view controller.

Comment: You're doing something that takes too long. Look at the backtrace and try to symbolicate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do very time-consuming tasks on the main thread. The crash is due to the populating process taking more than 10 seconds. It happened to me once in an infinite loop.

Start a new thread for this task, which will resume when your app enters foreground again. Tell the user what's going on, i.e. that the app is populating a database and that it may take some time. It is a good idea to show a progress indicator too.
As long as the user is kept well informed, he will accept to be patient.

Comment: "*As long as the user is kept well informed,* **he** *will accept to be patient*" - some users are *she* too, you know! Otherwise, your answer seems sound. :)